# How to make a non editable drop down combobox?

Tags: c#, combobox

I am having the combobox of dropdownstyle - dropdownlist it is noneditable but in windows 7, its back color cannot be changed.so i want a non editable drop down down combobox .

Comment: Could you clarify the question? it's a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way to set the backcolor

**First way**

set the combobox property

```
comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

then implement DrawItem event handler (sample code below)

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index > -1)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
    }
```

**Second way** 
set the combobox property

```
comboBox1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Then use the backcolor you needed for the combobox

Answer (score 0):

stay on your comboBox and search the dropstyle property from properties window and then choose dropdown list;